# Fixed field width number output in perl

Tags: perl, format

I have a random number between 0.001 and 1000 and I need perl to print it with a fixed column width of 5 characters. That is, if it's too long, it should be rounded, and if it's too short, it should be padded with spaces.

Everything I found online suggested using sprintf, but sprintf ignores the field width if the number is too long.

Is there any way to get perl to do this?

What doesn't work:

```
my $number = 0.001 + rand(1000);
my $formattednumber = sprintf("%5f", $number); 
print <<EOF;
   $formattednumber

EOF
```

Comment: You should make sure your example compiles. Don't type out code in the Stack Overflow editor. Copy and paste your _actual real_ code.

Comment: @simbabque fixed it, didn't copy paste because the other stuff in the code would just draw attention away from the problem

Comment: The problem was the missing quotes. Simply using `printf` instead of the several lines would make for a better [mcve] though. :)

Comment: @simbabque first you want what is in my code, now you don't want what is in my code ... there is no way to please you :D  anyway, I really like your approach in the answer, I never would have thought of that

Comment: And then I went on and posted an incomplete answer... shame on me! :D Actually I just wanted your code to compile, never mind the `print`. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define your `sprintf` pattern dynamically. The number of decimals depends on the number of digits on the left hand side of the decimal point.

This function will do that for you.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

sub round_to_col {
    my ( $number, $width ) = @_;

    my $width_int = length int $number;
    return sprintf(
        sprintf( '%%%d.%df', $width_int, $width - 1 - $width_int ),
        $number
    );
}

my $number = 0.001 + rand(1000);
say round_to_col( $number, 5);
```

Output could be:

```
 11.18
 430.7
 0.842
```

Comment: I had to replace the 5 by 4 to make space for the decimal point, and you probably meant to write $width in that place, so I put $width -1 where the 5 is now, but with that it works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: @fifaltra right, I fixed that. Thanks. So now you can pass in `5` and it will give 1 + point + 3, 2 + point + 2, and so on. Good job spotting it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pack` after the `sprintf`.  It may not be a computationally efficient approach, but it is relatively simple to implement and maintain:

```
my $formattednumber = pack ('A5', sprintf("%5f", $number));
```

Comment: This will not round as required. It merely chops off. I thought of using an outer `sprintf '%.5s'` initially, but it would also chop the decimals off. E.g. for `$number = 661.887709350259`, the output should be `661.9`, but this approach as well as the `sprintf` mentioned before will both give `661.8`, which is not rounded to the decimal.

Comment: You're right.  I did a very hasty job of reading the question -- that's my bad.  Thanks for the charitable critique.

Comment: Hm, I tried reading up on `pack` over on perldoc.perl.org, but I still don't really understand what it does here. Does it just cut off after the first five characters? (I don't really mind about the non-rounding, I said round in the question, but as we're dealing with random numbers anyway, it's not that important)

Comment: `pack` and `unpack` have many uses and are great for converting in and out, but the example above is just a straight text output.  'A' is ASCII text, and 5 means make it 5 characters.  That means if it's less than 5, it will pad it with spaces.  If it's more, it will chop off trailing characters.  When reading or writing fixed-width output, it's one of my favorite tools.  Do read @simbaque's comment.  While it may not matter for this example, it's an important consideration when using this particular construct.

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by simbabque does not cover all cases, so this is my improved version, just in case anyone also needs something like this:

```
sub round_to_col {
  my ( $number, $width ) = @_;

  my $width_int = length int $number;
  my $sprintf; 
  print "round_to_col error: number longer than width" if $width_int > $width;
  $sprintf = "%d" if $width_int == $width;
  $sprintf = "% d" if $width_int == $width - 1;
  $sprintf = sprintf( '%%%d.%df', $width_int, $width - 1 - $width_int )
    if $width_int < $width -1;
  return sprintf( $sprintf , $number );
}
```